# Angular data binding after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, data-binding

I have route like:
`/items/item/123/edit`
and controller (one controller for view and edit):

```
...
if ($routeParams.id) {
          $scope.itemId = $routeParams.id;
          $scope.editMode = true;

          Item.getBoxes({id: $routeParams.id}).$promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.data.boxId = [];

            angular.forEach(data, function (obj) {
              $scope.data.boxId.push(obj.id);
              $scope.boxCache[obj.id] = {id: obj.id, name: {id: obj.id, name: obj.name}};
            });

            $scope.items= data;
          });
        }
...
```

7 from 8 cases worked correctly but sometimes doesn't bind data to view.
I can't coll `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()` because their in progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use $scope.$apply only when if they are not in progress.

You can check if a $digest is already in progress by checking $scope.$$phase.

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  //$digest or $apply
}
```

**Use a safe apply, like this:**

```
$rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply();
```

Or another method use this service.

```
$timeout(function(),millisecond);
```

you can also use - `$evalAsync`
$evalAsync([expression], [locals]);

Check out this --> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Choosing between `$evalAsync` and `$timeout` depends on your circumstance:

- If code is queued using `$evalAsync` from a directive, it should run
  after the DOM has been manipulated by Angular, but before the browser
  renders.
- If code is queued using `$evalAsync` from a controller, it should run
  before the DOM has been manipulated by Angular (and before the
  browser renders) -- rarely do you want this
- if code is queued using `$timeout`, it should run after the DOM has been manipulated by Angular, and after the browser renders (which may cause flicker in some cases)

Comment: I tried this but `$scope.$$phase` was set to `$digest` even when data wasn't binding

Comment: `$timeout(function(), 500)` helps but I think this don't solve problem forever ;)

Comment: in your problem i think evalAsync will work fine ..because it works before dom reders, accept answer if works to help others